# Send WCF DataContract object with GUID attribute from node js

Tags: node.js, asp.net, express, wcf, soap

I am developing a management system with the following architecture:

- For the frontend, ReactJS
- For the backend, Express JS
- For web services, they were developed using WCF
- To store the data, SQL Server

The problem I have is updating a user from Express JS. I explain in more detail, this snippet belongs to my model class:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid idUser { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string fileNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string secondName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string firstLastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string secondLastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> sistemRole { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> appointment { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string level { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> category { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string area { get; set; }
}
```

My interface for the service contract is this:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{
    ...
 
    [OperationContract]
    string UpdateUserById(Guid id, User newUser);
    
    ...
}
```

My class for the service is this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    ...
    
    public string UpdateUserById(Guid id, User newUser)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DataEntities())
        {
            if (dbContext.users.Count(u => u.file_number == newUser.fileNumber && u.id_user != id) > 0)
            {
                return "UserCodeExists";
            }

            if (dbContext.users.Count(u => u.email == newUser.email && u.id_user != id) > 0)
            {
                return "UserEmailExists";
            }

            var currentUser = dbContext.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id_user == id);

            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                currentUser.file_number = newUser.fileNumber != null ? newUser.fileNumber : currentUser.file_number;
                currentUser.email = newUser.email != null ? newUser.email : currentUser.email;
                currentUser.first_name = newUser.firstName != null ? newUser.firstName : currentUser.first_name;
                currentUser.second_name = newUser.secondName != null ? newUser.secondName : currentUser.second_name;
                currentUser.first_lastname = newUser.firstLastname != null ? newUser.firstLastname : currentUser.first_lastname;
                currentUser.second_lastname = newUser.second_lastname != null ? newUser.second_lastname : currentUser.second_lastname;
                currentUser.date_info = DateTime.Now;
                currentUser.status = newUser.status != null ? newUser.status : currentUser.status;
                currentUser.system_role = newUser.systemRole != null ? newUser.systemRole : currentUser.system_role;
                currentUser.appointment = newUser.appointment != null ? newUser.appointment : currentUser.appointment;
                currentUser.level = newUser.level != null ? newUser.level : currentUser.level;
                currentUser.category = newUser.category != null ? newUser.category : currentUser.category;
                currentUser.area = newUser.area != null ? newUser.area : currentUser.area;

                int changes = dbContext.SaveChanges();
                string msgResult;
                
                if (changes > 0) msgResult = "UserUpdated" +
                        " DEBUG: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newUser, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore })
                    );
                else msgResult = "UserNotUpdated";

                return msgResult;
            }

            return "UserNotFound";
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

And in Express, making use of the [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) package, the middleware to process the request from the frontend is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const url = process.env.SERVICE_USER;

router.post('/update_id', async (req, res, next) => {
    const soap = require('soap');
    const args = {id: req.body.id, newUser: req.body.newUser};

    if (!args.id || !args.newUser) {
       const result = {UpdateUserByIdResult: {type: "Error",message: "BadRequest",data: req.body}};
    res.status(400).send(result);
    } else if (!utils.isGUID(args.id)) {
       const result = {UpdateUserByIdResult: {type: "Error",message: "NotIsGUID",data: args.id}};
       res.status(400).send(result);
    } else if (!utils.isUser(args.newUser)) {
       const result = {UpdateUserByIdResult: {type: "Error",message: "NotIsUser",data: args.newUser}};
       res.status(400).send(result);
    } else {
       soap.createClientAsync(url)
           .then((client) => client.UpdateUserByIdAsync(args))
           .then((result) => {
               args.newUser = utils.initUser(args.newUser); // Initialize a valid user nullifying the parameters not given
               res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(result[0].UpdateUserByIdResult).data);
            })
           .catch(next);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

My problem is that when I send the following request to update the user in question:

```
{
   "id": "54FD072D-F73A-43D1-878C-407D6400032C",
   "newUser": {
       "systemRole":"2fb9c2d8-5f41-eb11-8474-db2a67af11fe",
       "email":"nobody@gmail.com",
       "status":1,
       "fileNumber":"40718"
   }
}
```

To Express the request arrives without problems but when it arrives at the Web Service, the `newUser` parameter arrives as follows:

```
{
   "idUser": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "fileNumber": null,
   "username": null,
   "email": null,
   "firstName": null,
   "secondName": null,
   "firstLastname": null,
   "secondLastname": null,
   "date": null,
   "status": 0,
   "systemRole": "2fb9c2d8-5f41-eb11-8474-db2a67af11fe",
   "appointment": null,
   "level": null,
   "category": null,
   "area": null
}
```

Which is incorrect because the following should arrive for the `newUser` parameter:

```
{
   "idUser": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "fileNumber": "40718",
   "username": null,
   "email": "nobody@gmail.com",
   "firstName": null,
   "secondName": null,
   "firstLastname": null,
   "secondLastname": null,
   "date": null,
   "status": 1,
   "systemRole": "2fb9c2d8-5f41-eb11-8474-db2a67af11fe",
   "appointment": null,
   "level": null,
   "category": null,
   "area": null
}
```

With the `id` parameter there is no problem when it is received by the method. However, if I remove the `systemRole` field from the request everything proceeds without errors and the user is updated. But putting that field happens as I describe, in both cases the user is always updated. Can you help me?

Comment: Your problem should be an error in the insert statement. You should refer to the statement that can be inserted correctly to modify the field that was not successfully inserted into the database.

Comment: @TheobaldDu :: There is no problem with the database. When performing an insert in the database it is done successfully, and when updating as well, but if I include a value of type GUID in the request, then the object's properties arrive all null except for the GUID that I need to update.

Comment: Is GUID a foreign key?

Comment: Yes, GUID is a foreign key

Comment: You can try to query how to insert data with foreign keys to solve the problem.